# Backend Database for iOS Production Applications

Tags: ios, database, mongodb, firebase, elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to app development, and have no apps in the app store. However, the app that I have been working on is really progressing along.

The backend database that I have been using is Firebase, because it is so user friendly, easy to use, and easy to roll out an MVP. However, in the last couple of days I've really started hitting barriers with Firebase and how limited its querying functionality is, and how the code will become a "spaghetti" mess after a while. I'm looking for advice from some experienced programmers/developers.

Is Firebase viable for an app that depends heavily on searching? Can I couple Firebase with another service like Algolia and ElasticSearch to fix this problem? I'm concerned that if I press forward with Firebase and I eventually need to swap over to my own database that it will be pretty much impossible if I had 100,000 users. Especially factoring in the cost of such services after the app scales.

Or should I start my own backend (even though I have no experience with this at all) and move forward from there? I can learn, and don't have a problem putting forth effort in this area, but its a whole new journey for me. If this is the absolute right thing to do in order for me to have the ability to turn my app into a success story like your Uber's and AirBNB's, then I want to start out in this area and not get screwed on a transition from Firebase.

In summary, my question: If you were to start a company that could be the next Uber, where would you start your MVP? Firebase w/Elastic Search, your own custom backend, MongoDB, node.js, etc?

Thanks so much for the help and insight in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide which type of search queries you want to perform from your APP? Also, what will be the read/write ratio of requests you think your APP will be generating?

Comment: So my app has very similar features to apps like OfferUp and LetGo. I am trying to let users sell a product using my User Interface. So my app will let users post a product for sale and other users can buy it. This requires the ability to search items. The problem is Firebase only allows you to search for words starting at. If I type in "icrowave" it won't bring up "microwave". I need good search functionality and that's really the wall that I've been hitting.

Comment: As far as read/write ratio, i don't know for sure. I guess a lot of reads for every write.

Comment: What about the search queries? What type of search query do you want your app to perform?

Comment: Also, it's better if you update your question with read/write request ratio and type of queries which your app will be making.

Comment: Have you tried Firestore (beta), the new experimental NoSQL database within Firebase? With Firestore the querying is much more advanced, though still in its infancy. Also you can integrate Firestore with Algolia (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) and I'm currently writing another integration for Elasticsearch, but it's still too early to release it.

Comment: If Firestore is too "beta" for you, you can also integrate Algolia with Firebase (https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/3rd-party-service/firebase-algolia/) or Elasticsearch using Flashlight (https://github.com/firebase/flashlight)